# Terminator interface inside tilda emulator?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, gnome-terminator, tilda

Does anyone knows how to use Terminator inside Tilda?
I use Tilda emulator a lot but sometimes I need to have different terminal windows open to check things out and I don't want to open Terminator separatedly.
Does anyone knows?

Comment: What do you mean by “use Terminator inside Tilda”? Both are X11 terminal emulator, i.e. they provide a terminal in an X11 window. Running one “inside” the other doesn't make sense. Why do you use Tilda if you want Terminator?

Comment: Well, I use tilda because of it's drop down function but I like terminator split windows function so, I think there should be a way to combine this two before having to create a custom script or something alike

Comment: Terminator already offers the drop-down function. I use that currently.

Comment: I made this as an answer so I could add screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same question as this, because I though Terminator affords the ability for split windows, but @RAKK is right, `tmux` can be used as well, here's how:

First, I wanted to have a customized `bash` (which I start with command `mybash`) start up, that can be done in Tilda with `/bin/bash -i -c 'LINES=10 COLUMNS=150 mybash'` under Preferences / Title and Command / Command (`LINES=10 COLUMNS=150` is because I get `your 131072x1 screen size is bogus. expect trouble`, this prevents it from showing second time):

[image: tildaconfig]

Then, once Tilda starts, try running:

```
tmux new "nano ~/test.txt"
```

... and once `nano` has started, press Ctrl-B, then `%` (Shift+4); you should get something like this:

[image: tilda2]

Note that sometimes when Tilda hides, and is shown again, it will not show the same layout of windows you saw last time, not sure how to restore it.

Some further resources:

- [Tmux: A Simple Start](https://www.sitepoint.com/tmux-a-simple-start/)
- [tmux and mouse mode - Dan Lowe](http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/07/16/tmux-and-mouse-mode/)
- [GitHub - tmuxinator/tmuxinator: Manage complex tmux sessions easily](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator)

Answer (score 1):

There's the option of using tmux if you're looking for Terminator's split window function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Perhaps you could explain _how_ to use tmux for this?

Comment: Maybe this could help, how could I use tmux?

Comment: @Braiam Indeed I am not allowed yet to comment on the author's post. I require 50 reputation :S

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to stay with Tilda for the "drop-down" function. Terminator already offers this. To use it, right click on the Terminator window and select Preferences. Then select `Window state:` as `Hidden`.

[image: Window state: Hidden]

You can customise the hotkey in the preferences as well with `Keybindings` > `hide_window`.

[image: Keybindings > hide_window]